# Changing the time format in freemarker

Tags: date, time, freemarker

I have the following time format:

Dec 29, 2016 10:57:58 PM

How can I display it in a model of days ago. Like 10days or 20days using Freemarker?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker templates don't do calendar calculations, or at least not unless you add a `TemplateMethodModelEx` for them. But in principle such data should come from the data-model, rather than calculated by the template.

Though, depending on how you define "days ago", something like `((.now?long - someDate?long) / 86400000)?ceiling` might works, assuming `someDate` is a real date-time value and not just a string. But it's ugly.